# UWP/XAML custom property which can "host" controls

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I'm actually creating an UserControl for a custom ListView.
What I'm trying to achieve is the same thing as this post: [Hide or Show stackpanel of ListViewItem with VisualStateManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874238/hide-or-show-stackpanel-of-listviewitem-with-visualstatemanager). I already implemented the code and it works, but now I want to make it more "generic" so I've created a user control.

My control is divided into two grid. The upper grid and the collapsed hidden grid.

And I want to use my user control like this:

```
<controls:ExpandableListView ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectedObjects}">
    <controls:ExpandableListView.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
    </controls:ExpandableListView.Header>
    <controls:ExpandableListView.ExpandedContent>
         <Button Content="test 2" />
    </controls:ExpandableListView.ExpandedContent>
</controls:ExpandableListView>
```

The `Header` property is the content which will be placed in the upper grid, and the ExpandedContent is the content placed in the collapsed grid.

In my user control I have:

```
<ListView x:Name="LIST" SelectionChanged="LIST_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">

    <!-- Item container style -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- Item template -->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid x:Name="GRID_1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Header}" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="GRID_2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=ExpandedContent}" />
                </Grid>

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"></VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="GRID_2.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

There is the code behind of the user control

```
public sealed partial class ExpandableListView : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource", 
            typeof(IEnumerable), 
            typeof(ExpandableListView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Header",
            typeof(Object),
            typeof(ExpandableListView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExpandedContent",
            typeof(Object),
            typeof(ExpandableListView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IEnumerable; }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public Object Header
    {
        get { return (Object)this.GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public Object ExpandedContent
    {
        get { return (Object)this.GetValue(ExpandedContentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ExpandedContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public ExpandableListView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.LIST.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void LIST_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void SetInEditMode()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Selected", true);
    }

    private void SetInViewMode()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is how can I do to display the content defined between my `<controls:ExpandableListView.ExpandedContent>`and `<controls:ExpandableListView.Header>` inside my ListView. I'm using the ItemTemplate to format the Item cell and I have `Header` and `ExpandedContent` which are `FrameworkElement`s. But it seems it doesn't work like that. I also tried with a ContentControl, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add content attribute to specify which property will be used as content. Example:

```
[ContentProperty("ExpandedContent")]
public sealed partial class ExpandableListView : UserControl
{
...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExpandedContent",
            typeof(Object),
            typeof(ExpandableListView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
...
    public Object ExpandedContent
    {
        get { return (Object)this.GetValue(ExpandedContentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ExpandedContentProperty, value); }
    }

...
}
```

Also I prefer to use `nemeof()` in dependency property declaration. It makes code safer to refactoring and renaming:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ExpandedContent),
        typeof(Object),
        typeof(ExpandableListView),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Grid x:Name="GRID_2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyUsersContent }"/>
   </Grid>
```

In your control CS file

```
public class YourControl{  

     public Object MyUsersContent
     {
         get { return (Object)GetValue(MyUsersContentProperty); }
         set { SetValue(MyUsersContentProperty, value); }
     }
    
     public static readonly DependencyProperty MyUsersContentProperty =
                   DependencyProperty.Register("MyUsersContent", 
                       typeof(Object), typeof(YoutControl), new PropertyMetadata());   
 }
```

This is probably the easiest way to do it. This is the reason we need to see your code though. Because it makes a difference how you implement this feature. If you have trouble with the binding then you can grab your control in the OnApplyTemplate function and pump it in manually.

Before you continue though I would highly recommend doing this tutorial. It will give you an idea of how this, and many other issues you'll face should be solved.

[How to create a Custom Control in WPF](https://www.wpftutorial.net/howtocreateacustomcontrol.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edit my original post added the code behind of the user control.
Also tried to add `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource=
            {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MyUsersContent }"/>` and it does't works unfortunatly.

Comment: This is why I said the rest of the code matters. Instead of using templated parent just bind directly to it.